# How to run UFT scripts through Jira

Tags: jira, qtp, hp-uft, jira-rest-api, uft14

I need to run my UFT scripts through Atlassian Jira and upload the run reports back to the same. Please help me with the steps to integrate UFT with Jira.

I installed Zephyr add-in to my Jira and therefore I didn't get any idea to integrate with UFT scripts

Comment: Can u specify? want to have entries in jira which get's moved when the status from UFT Scripts gets failed/passed/whatever? Or do you want to start scripts using jira?

Comment: @Jonas  After running a test script from UFT, it should automatically update the respective test case status as Pass/Fail in Jira.

Comment: From where do you trigger the UFT case? ALM?

Answer (score -1):

My proposal would be:
Jira --> Zephyr --> Jenkins([Zephyr Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Zephyr+For+Jira+Test+Management+Plugin)) ---> UFT ([Jenkins Plugin](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Jenkins.htm))

This is the Integration Chain that "is given"

Otherwise you have to implement your own Automation / integration code using ZAPI and COM [Automation for UFT](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/z_Ch_AutoScriptsIntro.htm)